# sync problem in stereo image

Tags: ros, image-geometry, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

modified stereo_camera_model.cpp in image_geometry, now I can receive /stereo/disparity message, but still there is problem in image sync when I want to view by:  rosrun image_view stereo_view stereo:=/stereo image:=image_rect  there is just three gray windows (no image) and a [WARN] message as below
any suggestion, please?

```
[ WARN] [1297946062.739511145]: [stereo_view] Low number of synchronized left/right/disparity triplets received.
Left images received:      104 (topic '/stereo/left/image_rect')
Right images received:     102 (topic '/stereo/right/image_rect')
Disparity images received: 18 (topic '/stereo/disparity')
Synchronized triplets: 0
Possible issues:
               * stereo_image_proc is not running.
                 Does `rosnode info /stereo_view_1297946016943512050` show any connections?
               * The cameras are not synchronized.
                 Try restarting stereo_view with parameter _approximate_sync:=True
               * The network is too slow. One or more images are dropped from each triplet.
                 Try restarting stereo_view, increasing parameter 'queue_size' (currently 5)
[ WARN] [1297946077.740713539]: [stereo_view] Low number of synchronized left/right/disparity triplets received.
Left images received:      147 (topic '/stereo/left/image_rect')
Right images received:     155 (topic '/stereo/right/image_rect')
Disparity images received: 29 (topic '/stereo/disparity')
Synchronized triplets: 0
Possible issues:
               * stereo_image_proc is not running.
                 Does `rosnode info /stereo_view_1297946016943512050` show any connections?
               * The cameras are not synchronized.
                 Try restarting stereo_view with parameter _approximate_sync:=True
               * The network is too slow. One or more images are dropped from each triplet.
                 Try restarting stereo_view, increasing parameter 'queue_size' (currently 5)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9108/sync-problem-in-stereo-image/) by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on 2011-02-18**:
I'm prosilica camera, prosilica_node in camera_drivers.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-17**:
What cameras and driver are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're running two prosilica_camera instances, probably they are not synchronized - that is, left and right image time stamps don't match up exactly. All the image_pipeline nodes assume exact synchronization for stereo (the ideal case) by default. Since you're getting disparity images from stereo_image_proc, you must have started it with ~approximate_sync set to True. You need to do the same with stereo_view, as the warning message recommends.

A second potential problem is that stereo_image_proc is not running at frame rate. You can see that stereo_view is getting less than one disparity image for every five image pairs. I guess the Prosilica images are too high resolution (or your computer not beefy enough :) for stereo_image_proc to keep up. stereo_view keeps a queue of size 5 (by default) on each input topic, which means the left/right image messages may drop off the queues by the time their matching disparity image arrives. The solution is to increase ~queue_size.

**tl;dr** Try this:

```
rosrun image_view stereo_view stereo:=/stereo image:=image_rect _approximate_sync:=True _queue_size:=10
```

If you just want to view the disparity images (no synchronization required), you can do

```
rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/stereo/disparity
```

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4